# Proper placement of "toCSV" function: In each object, or in a generic class?

Tags: c++, qt

There is a set of classA objects, containing several data fields, and inside each classA object, there is a set of classB objects containing additional data fields.

At some point I want to generate a CSV file.

My initial approach is to implement a .toCSV() in both classA and classB and do the following in main.cpp:

```
string completecsv;
foreach(classA ca, setOfClassA)
    completecsv.append(ca.toCSV());
```

And inside classA.toCSV()

```
string csv;
csv.append(field1);
csv.append(field2);
csv.append(...);
foreach(classB cb, setOfClassB)
        csv.append(cb.toCSV());

return csv;
```

And finally in classB.toCSV()

```
string csv;
csv.append(field1);
csv.append(field2);
csv.append(...);

return csv;
```

Now, my other approach was to create a class named something like OutputManager, that is in charge of everything regarding the CSV generation, keeping the MVC pattern more clearly separated.

Any thoughts regarding this two approaches?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there are lots of properties of `classA` and `classB` that make sense to include in a report, regardless of the report format (CSV, XML, Json, etc.), then it sounds like `classA` and `classB` are actually data classes without much logic.

If that is the case, I'd keep the report generation separate from them to easily make it possible to extend the reporting mechanism with other output formats if needed.

To cater for a hierarchical output format (like XML or Json), it might make sense to let types that you read properties from to also expose a 'children' property, so that it can be looped through and applied recursively.

For each type that gets output, it could expose a name-value collection of its 'outputtable' data that the `OutputManager` then chooses what to do with.

Something like this, where the `OutputManager` would get the 'root' `IOutputtable` (`classB` in this case) and just loop over its name-values and then do the same with its children, recursively.

```
interface IOutputtable
{
    NameValueCollection Items { get; }
    IEnumerable<IOutputtable> Children { get; }
}

class A : IOutputtable
{
    private int _baz;

    public NameValueCollection Items {
        get {
            return new NameValueCollection() {
                { "baz", _baz.ToString() }
            };
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IOutputtable> Children {
        get {
            return Enumerable.Empty<IOutputtable>();
        }
    }
}

class B : IOutputtable
{
    private int _foo;
    private string _bar;
    private List<A> _as = new List<A>();

    public NameValueCollection Items {
        get {
            return new NameValueCollection() {
                { "foo", _foo.ToString() },
                { "bar", _bar }
            };
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<IOutputtable> Children {
        get { return _as; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I fully agree with the statements made, keeping the output function separate helps when there might be a need for different serializations in the future. However, i really do not like having a C++ question answered with (i can only guess) C# example code...

Comment: Haha! I had just answered another C# question elsewhere and didn't realize this wasn't also one :) - fixing now